# How do I return false and stop an email being sent if one or more if statements is false Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I'm having an issue with a contact form.

I have 2 if statements and I return false at the end of the second one, but when I execute this, with both fields empty, its happy, and my error msgs pop up, and the email doesn't send. but if I only enter information in the second input field, it thinks the form is filled out, even with the first field empty.

How do I stop the email from sending if either one of the if statements is false?

#### My code

```
function checkForm(){
    if   (streetAddress.value == "") {  
            addressErrorMsg.style.display="block";
    }
                        
    if   (fullname.value == "") {  
            nameErrorMsg.style.display="block";
     
       return false;
    }
    else{                       
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return false....

Comment: can you provide the code where you actually send the email?

Comment: Why not return `false` in the first condition as well?

Comment: @David I think the OP wants to show both error messages if both fields are empty.

Comment: I have returned false, after the second if statement, my question is why is the first if statements value being forgotten?

Comment: @Juhana: Ah, I didn't notice that the error messages were different elements.  You're right.

Comment: you check "" in your if loop and also check null

Comment: @GaneshRengarajan have you ever seen value be null? Please give me a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the state and have one return statement at the end.

```
function checkForm(){
    var isValid = true;
    if   (streetAddress.value == "") {  
            addressErrorMsg.style.display="block";
            isValid = false;
    }

    if   (fullname.value == "") {  
            nameErrorMsg.style.display="block";

       isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

And looking at your code, I am hoping you have

```
var addressErrorMsg = document.getElementById("SomeId");
```

above your code and you are not just using the id to reference the element.

Comment: Yes i do have my variable declared above, and thank you, you fixed my problem! Much appreciated! @epascarello

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkForm(){
    var validate = true;
    if   (streetAddress.value == "") {  
            addressErrorMsg.style.display="block";
            validate = false;
    }

    if   (fullname.value == "") {  
            nameErrorMsg.style.display="block";
            validate = false;

    }
    return validate;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I just randomly stumbled upon this question/answer, but I wouldn't be surprised if the reason for the now-removed downvote is because you didn't bother explaining anything; you just posted code. Some of us probably understand what you did and why, but it doesn't help the OP to just post code.

Comment: I downvoted your answer when it was literally only "use a flag to keep track of error message" (or similar, I don't remember exact wording) which you then replaced during the 5-minute grace period with the block of code. You obviously knew it wasn't a good answer because you replaced it immediately, so I don't understand why you cry for explanation for the downvote.

Comment: @PSR: This has been asked and answered *ad nauseum* on Meta and the overwhelming response from the community has been to not require supplying a reason for a downvote.  Downvotes can mean many things, such as the answer being unhelpful or unclear or just plain incorrect.  Even a correct answer delivered in a poor way can be downvoted.  Conversely, upvotes are equally subjective.  It is not the responsibility of the voter to improve the content you provide, or to help you provide better content.  Voting is simply the community's reaction to said content.

Comment: @David Not to stray from the OP's question, but I've always thought if you downvote, you should be getting messages in your inbox for edits to the answer. That way, if the answer is modified in a positive and better way (in your opinion), you have the opportunity to know, go back and see it, and change your vote if you want. Otherwise, people downvote and never go back, or know what happens to it

Comment: @Ian: With that I completely agree.  Looks like it's a declined feature request, though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/148400

Comment: @David Ahh nice! I've been meaning to look up whether it's been asked/requested (and maybe request it if not), so thanks for the link. It looks like there's **several** related questions as well. There are a lot of answers with different opinions (some of which I've thought about before) and I like most of them, I was just thinking of keeping it simple for the developers of SO to not have to do too much work, yet implement this. It's a shame they don't :(